# deviseを実装。モデルとコントローラーにコードを書き、update時にpasswordのバリデーションを解除したい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

プロフィールページのデザインを改善したので、
プロフィールを入力して、出来を確認しようと考えたのですが、
deviseのvalidationで躓いてしまいました( ;∀;)

#### 前提・実現したいこと

プロフィール更新時のパスワードvalidationを解除したい。
deviseを実装しています。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

自分なりにdeviseにおけるパスワード解除を実装したつもりなのですが、
プロフィールを更新すると

```
Password can't be blank
```

と、拒絶されてしまいます。

このようなエラーも発生していました。

```
 DEPRECATION WARNING: You attempted to assign a value which is not explicitly `true` or `false` ("{:autofocus=>true}") to a boolean column. Currently this value casts to `false`. This will change to match Ruby's semantics, and will cast to `true` in Rails 5. If you would like to maintain the current behavior, you should explicitly handle the values you would like cast to `false`. (called from update_without_current_password at /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/models/user.rb:79)
```

#### 該当のソースコード

【user.rb】

```
・・・・省略・・・・
  def password_required?
    provider.blank?  # provider属性に値があればパスワード入力免除
  end

  def update_without_current_password(params, *options)
    params.delete(:current_password)

    if params[:password].blank? && params[:password_confirmation].blank?
      params.delete(:password)
      params.delete(:password_confirmation)
    end

    result = update_attributes(params, *options)
    clean_up_passwords
    result
  end
・・・・省略・・・・
```

【registrations_controller.rb】

```
・・・・省略・・・・
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    #if update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
    if resource.update_without_current_password(account_update_params)
      yield resource if block_given?
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
      respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_current_password(params)
  end
・・・・省略・・・・
```

#### 試したこと

[Devise でユーザーがパスワードなしでアカウント情報を変更するのを許可](http://easyramble.com/user-account-update-without-password-on-devise.html)こちらを参考にしてコードを書いてみました。

足りない情報がありましたら、リクエストお願い致します。

teratailでも質問しています。
[deviseを実装。モデルとコントローラーにコードを書き、update時にpasswordのバリデーションを解除したい。](https://teratail.com/questions/55246)

Comment: 現在、[GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/)で用いられる ```で囲む構文には対応していません。 [質問や回答に書いたソースコードをきれいに表示したい - スタック⚫オーバーフロー Meta](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/15185)

Comment: 失礼しました。teratailと同じ構造かと勘違いしていました。気を付けます。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: もし良ければteratailのリンクを貼っていただけないでしょうか。 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2246/15185

Comment: あと、回答のコメントで言及されている"厳しく管理されている"について。どのように管理されているかは、[ツアー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com)を見たり、[ヘルプセンター](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/)を見ると良いかもしれません。

Comment: sun-solar-arrowさん、質問の方にリンクを貼りました！
ツアーとヘルプセンターですが、目を通しておきます。

Comment: teratailへのリンクが関係ない質問へのリンクになっていたので修正しました。**同じ質問について**他のサイトでどんなやり取りが行われているのか見れるように、ということでリンクを貼っていただきたいのであって、この質問と関係ない質問へのリンクでは意味がありません。sun-solar-arrowさんが当サイトでの議論のURLを記載されていますが、「マルチポスト」で調べると色々見つかります。

Comment: 間違えました。
気を付けます。

Comment: 回答の方はどうでしょうか？もし、よかったらお願いします。

Comment: @s.k 回答の方というのは、解決したらどうすればいいかということでしょうか。(リンクは貼れないと思います)とりあえず自分自身で回答を投稿して、承認という機能をお使いください。[参考](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) あと、"teratailのリンク"について。もっと詳しく書けばよかったですね、すみません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

【user.rb】

```
def password_required?
  provider.blank?
end
```

【new.html.erb】

```
<% if f.object.password_required? %>
   ・・・省略・・・
<% end %>
```

この2つがdeviseの実装を妨害していたようです。
一見、関係ないように見えるのですが…

Comment: すみません。
完全な回答のつもりで投稿したのですが。
情報が少ないので、完全な回答にはなっていないということですか？

Comment: あ、マジですか、それはすいません。私のミスです…

Comment: そして、削除票の撤回ってできるのかな。。しばしお待ちを。。

Comment: 削除票の取り消しはできなさそうです。もし削除票が集まってこの回答が削除されてしまったら、質問か削除された回答(もし見えてたら)を「通報」して、モデレーターに削除取り消しの対応をお願いするのが良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ここは、teratailよりも投稿内容に関して厳しく管理されているんですね。
以後、気を付けます。

Comment: そう、ですね。スタックオーバーフローは、Q&Aを蓄積、整理していくためにシステム的に特化したような側面があって、なので「厳しい」という印象を受けるのかもしれないです。何か、スタッオーバーフローというサイト自体に納得できないことや、どうかと思うことなどがあれば、メタの方でそれを投稿すると、良いかもしれないです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
もう少し、勉強してみますね。

Comment: 自己解決した場合は一言添えるといいかもしれません。追加情報を回答で書いてしまう方も見えるので簡潔に書いてしまうと解答なのか追加情報なのか分からず、削除票でレビューが通ってしまう可能性があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。一言添えますね。